# Check if variable is jQuery when importing with webpack

Tags: jquery, npm, webpack

It is pretty simple to test if your variable is of type jQuery when you just use a script tag to load jQuery from a CDN, but I am looking for an easy way to do this when you are using npm and webpack to import jquery.  My sample import is

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'

const $myElement = $('.my-element')

const isJQuery = ($element) => {
  return (
    typeof $element === 'object' &&
    $element.length &&
    $element[0] instanceof HTMLElement
  )
}

console.log(isJQuery($myElement)) // prints true
```

Is there a more forward way to check that the $myElement contains a valid element?

When you use npm and webpack to import jQuery, there is no variable window.jQuery or window.$.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import * as $ from 'jquery';

const isJQuery = $element => $element instanceof $;

const $myElement = $('.my-element');

console.log(isJQuery($myElement)) // prints true
```

`$myElement isntanceof $` does return `true` also when jQuery is loaded through Webpack.

Comment: var $myElement = $('.my-element')
undefined
$myElement instanceof $
VM13544:1 Uncaught TypeError: Function has non-object prototype 'undefined' in instanceof check
    at Function.[Symbol.hasInstance] (<anonymous>)
    at eval (eval at isJQuery (index.js:NaN), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at isJQuery (index.js:20)
    at SimpleGraph.checkOptions (index.js:39)
    at new SimpleGraph (index.js:35)
    at eval (index.js:11)
    at Module../line-graph/index.js (line-graph.js:97)
    at __webpack_require__ (line-graph.js:20)
    at line-graph.js:84
    at line-graph.js:87

Comment: Dis you try doing you import this way ?:
`import $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: Yes, and still got the error: "function has non-object prototype"